# Does any of the light from optical pump go into the end product laser light?

Tags: laser

Does any of the light from optical pump go into the end product laser light? Or is it all adsorbed in the lasing medium?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically some of the pump light might be found along the output beam. Unless, of course, some kind of filter is used to block it.

But do you consider it part of the "laser light"? It's not at the same wavelength as the laser output, and it's not coherent with the laser output. To me, that makes it a "no".